# In Rails 3,is there an event that fires before the connection string is set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3,is there an event that fires before the connection string is set?

I want to override the connection string on based on some criteria, and want the entire request to use this overriden connection string.

Was hoping I could do this easily by overriding some event that fires before it is set?

Comment: What is a connection string? Database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you find a fitting notification (`ActiveSupport::Notifications`). See http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3 for a great overview.